# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable; Error in a formula

Tags: python, numpy

I want to program a formula and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

The formula is:

```
logL = len(eps)*(np.log(np.sqrt(OMEGA)) - np.log(beta(p,q)) + p*DELTA) +
    np.sum(p*np.sqrt(OMEGA)*eps/(np.sqrt(sigma_2))) -
    0.5*np.sum(np.log(sigma_2)) - 
    (p+q) * np.sum(np.log(1+np.exp(np.sqrt(OMEGA)*eps / (np.sqrt(sigma_2))) + DELTA))
```

The following functions are used:

```
def garch_filter(omega, alpha, beta, eps):
    iT = len(eps)
    sigma_2 = np.zeros(iT)

    for i in range(iT):
        if i==0:
            #sigma_2[i] = omega/(1-alpha-beta)
            sigma_2[i] = np.var(eps)
        else:
            sigma_2[i] = omega + alpha*eps[i-1]**2 + beta*sigma_2[i-1]
    return sigma_2

def OMEGAf(p,q):
    OMEGA = polygamma(1,p) + polygamma(1,q)

    return OMEGA

def DELTAf(p,q):
    DELTA = digamma(p) - digamma(q)  

    return DELTA
```

In the code the `*` sign between `p` and `DELTA` is disappeared, but it is there. 
I hope somebody want/can help me.

Comment: Your code listing in the question is incomplete. You should at least show how values such as `OMEGA` and `sigma_2` are defined and initialised.

Comment: What is "beta"?  In this code it is used as a function ``beta(p,q)``, but would generate an error if beta had previously been assigned a numpy.float64 type.

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted it, but now I get the following error:

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'rv_frozen' and 'int'